# C# After Try/Catch, back to Foreach Loop?

Tags: c#, try-catch, console-application

I built some CodeExample:

```
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
              foreach (String hello in helloList)
              {
                     DoSomething(hello);
              }
      }

      public static void DoSomething(String hello)
      {
               try
               {
                    //Some Code
               }
               catch (Exception exception)
               {
                    Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                    Console.ReadKey();
               }
       }
```

I'm iterating through a List and sometimes it happens, that the program walks into the Catch. Now, the Program terminates, after `Console.ReadKey();` - but what I want is, getting back to the foreach Loop and continue the work.. How can I achieve this?
From the Catch, I only need the Message..

EDIT:
OriginalCode:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     //Some unimportant code
              StringCollection bilderUnterLink = HoleBildLinksVonWebseite(htmlInhaltUnterLink);
              foreach (String bild in bilderUnterLink)
              {
                     BildAbspeichern(bild);
              }                                 
     }

public static void BildAbspeichern(String bildLink)
        {
            string speicherOrt = webseite + @"/" + bildLink;
            string gueltigerBildLink;
            if (bildLink.Contains("http://"))
            {
                gueltigerBildLink = bildLink;
            }
            else
            {
                gueltigerBildLink = "http://" + webseite + @"/" + bildLink;
            }

            if (!File.Exists(webseite + @"/" + Path.GetFileName(gueltigerBildLink)))
            {
                try
                {
                    WebClient client = new WebClient();
                    client.DownloadFile(gueltigerBildLink, speicherOrt);
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Bild gepeichert:    " + "{0}", gueltigerBildLink));
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
        }
```

I think thats enough important code.. And it terminates, I know it shouldn't..

Comment: There's no reason that code *should* terminate after `ReadKey()`, with the exception of some very special cases such as thread aborts. It should be fine as it is - please provide a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: That will already go back to the `foreach`. Are you sure the `foreach` isn't just reaching the end?

Comment: Sample code looks fine. Could you provide the original code?

Comment: Ok I will provide the original needed code.. Just some minutes :)

Comment: Code added - maybe because of the Webclient class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is terminating, I suspect the exception is simply **not inside the `try`**; so... change that:

```
public static void BildAbspeichern(String bildLink)
{
    try {
         ... all your code
    } catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Other notes:

- note I changed to `Console.Error` for error output; good practice (this writes to `stderr` rather than `stdout`)
- waiting for a keypress without telling the user you are waiting may confuse; personally, I'd remove the `ReadKey()` completely
- you should use `using` on `WebClient`, since it is `IDisposable`, i.e.

  ```
  using(var client = new WebClient()) {
      client.DownloadFile(gueltigerBildLink, speicherOrt);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

This will continue the loop after the exception.

Since you catch the exception inside the `DoSomething()` method, this will not break the loop. Only an unhandled exception inside `DoSomething()` will break the loop.